# Linq - How can I create a DateTime from time values stored in three different columns?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I create a DateTime from time values stored in three different columns using linq to sql? All of the fields are of type `smallint` and the following is an example of the fields in the database:

```
hour(column1) minute (column2) second (column3) 
17                34                 45
```

This is what I have tried, but I have had no luck.

```
Saat = Convert.ToDateTime(c.HOUR_ + '/' + c.MINUTE_ + '/' + c.SECOND_)
```

Comment: How you want to create datetime value by only using **H:M:S**??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to create a `DateTime` with only a Time portion.

`Hour/minute/second` won't give you a valid date. You have two options. You can use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558.aspx) or you can use the overload for the [DateTime constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx) that takes a year, month, day, hour, minute, second.